# how to get table records where columns not equal to other table columns

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 tables with same pk(and more different pks),
i want to get all records from table A that those columns not exist in table B.

**color and country are pks in both tables(there is more but not shared)**

i tried to do this:

```
select A.color, A.country from A 
where not exists(select 1 from B where B.country = A.country and B.color = A.color)
group by A.country, A.color
```

and this:

```
select A.color, A.country from A, B
where B.country <> A.country and B.color <> A.color
group by A.country, A.color
```

but always i get records that country and color exist in table B

what do i do wrong?

(i know the db design is bad, but i didn't write it)

Comment: The `not exists` works for me: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea1109edd60eafc50de9cad8491b2011). Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your issue and the expected output.

Comment: What's wrong with `select color, country from A group by color, country except select color, country from B group by color, country`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the color+country pairs, then you could use the set operator EXCEPT (which should match the OP's WHERE NOT EXISTS query)

```
/* use set operator 'EXCEPT' to subtract sets */
select * from A
except
select * from B;
```

To remove the colors and countries as individual distinct values something like this

```
/* remove individual distinct values */
select A.color, A.country from A 
where not exists(select 1 from B where B.country = A.country) and
      not exists(select 1 from B where B.color = A.color)
group by A.country, A.color;
```